# Whats the best way to add arrays in php dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

I am iterating over data dynamically. The data contains three fields that I want to insert into an array.. Array(field1,field2,field3)..and then insert that array into another array (nest it). Then nest another array into the main array. The problem is that i dont know how to  do it so that I get one array out of the loop that will contain all the nested arrays.

```
$myArray=array();
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $myArray+= Array(field1,field2,field3);
    }
```

How do you add them dynamically..I know I do it the wrong way..But how do you do it?!

Comment: PDO already does that with fetchArray

Comment: Use the `[]` to append arrays: `$myArray[] = $row`

Comment: Or if you only need a few fields for some reason `$myArray[] = array($row['f1'], $row['f9']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) {
    $myArray[] = array($row['field1'], $row['field2'], $row['field3']);
}
```

If you want to add the whole content of each row, i.e. every field in a row, you can just use

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1) {
    $myArray[] = $row;
}
```

or just this single line:

```
while ($myArray[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Then you can access e.g. field2 of row 5 with $myArray[4]['field2']

In your question you use the function mysql_fetch_array. Please use mysql_fetch_assoc as this is most certainly the better way. mysql_fetch_array returns every value twice, once with a numeric index (e.g. 1, but note that this depends on the order of the queried fields in your query!), once with an associative index. mysql_fetch_assoc only returns each value once with its associative index (e.g. 'field2').

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_assocArray Pop?

```
$myArray=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
        array_push($myArray, $row['field1'], $row['field2'], $row['field3']);
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: This would work, but only if you'd use $row['field1'] instead of field1, etc. Your answer is no valid php.